# PHP and LSP mode - code formatting?

Tags: lsp-mode, web-mode

I have setup web-mode and lsp mode for PHP programming in my config file. It is very minimal and `flymake` works perfectly.

I am struggling to find a way to get code formatting to work. I was told that I could install PHP_beautifier from Pear (which i did) and use it in emacs. But I am not sure how exactly?

There is no such package in emacs either.

My question is what is the best way to auto-format code on save with PHP?

```lisp
(use-package lsp-mode
  :ensure t
  :config
  (setq lsp-headerline-breadcrumb-enable nil) ;; works
  (setq lsp-enable-symbol-highlighting nil) ;; works
  (setq lsp-signature-render-documentation nil)
  (setq lsp-completion-provider :none) ;; works
  (setq lsp-diagnostics-provider :flymake) ;; underline error
  )

(use-package web-mode
  :ensure t
  :init
  (setq web-mode-code-indent-offset 4)
  (setq web-mode-markup-indent-offset 4)
  (setq web-mode-enable-sql-detection t)

  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Check whether `web-mode-enable-auto-indentation` is enabled. It should be so for GUI Emacs (not in terminal) by default. With this option enabled, buffer contents should be re-indented automatically.

Optionally, call `M-x web-mode-buffer-indent` (`C-c TAB` or `C-c C-i` and available from menu). For example, this way:

```el
(defun my-web-mode-hook ()
  (add-hook 'after-save-hook #'web-mode-buffer-indent))

(add-hook 'web-mode-hook 'my-web-mode-hook)
```

The following part of the answer addresses the question(s) more generally.

It's quite typical to install [php-mode](https://github.com/emacs-php/php-mode) for PHP programming language syntax highlighting and indentation. Whilst [web-mode](https://web-mode.org) is more suitable for the scripts containing a mix of languages. If your case is the former, I'd suggest to use **php-mode** and install one of the [PHP language servers](https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/lsp-phpactor/) for the mentioned **lsp-mode** to direct requests to.

Note, that since *Emacs 29* built-in LSP client **Eglot** is provided, which also would still require installation of a language server.

Another thing to note, you might find [tree-sitter usage](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/how-to-get-started-tree-sitter) useful (support for which is also built-in since *Emacs 29*).

Comment: Most of the time, my PHP code has PHP and HTML in the same file. Hence why I use web-mode. Unlike PPHP mode, it doesn't have a formatter.

Comment: I added some ideas for web-mode usage to the answer.